Vlocity Data Raptor - CONCAT Function Issue [NEW 4/2024]
From the original question here:
Example, CONCAT(list:fullName, " - ", list:relationship) to list:Result
Expected outcome:
[
  {
    list: Result: "fullName1 - Child"
  },
  {
    list: Result: "fullName2 - Spouse"
  },
  ...
]

but getting unexpected outcome:
[
  {
    list: Result: "fullName1fullName2  - ChildSpouse"
  }
]

I'm in a similar scenario where I'd like to concatenate 2 attributes in a object list but running into the issue where the concatenated string is adding the first value (name) in succession then appends the second value after in succession. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!


Your first formula (FILTER(LIST(%combinedRelationships%),'relation!=NULL') seems to be causing the issue.
I replicated your example and also ended up with the result you mentioned.
I changed the second formula to:
CONCAT(combinedRelationships:relatedParty:fullName," - ",combinedRelationships:relation)
which gave me the correct results of:
{
  "combinedRelationships": [
    {
      "Result": "Kyong K Plessinger - CHILD",
      "relation": "CHILD",
      "relatedParty": {
        "type": "PERSON",
        "fullName": "Kyong K Plessinger",
        "person": {
          "middlename": "K",
          "firstName": "Kyong",
          "lastName": "Plessigner"
        }
      },
      "originatingParty": {
        "type": "PERSON",
        "id": "",
        "fullName": "Jann M Lumis",
        "person": {
          "middlename": "M",
          "firstName": "Jann",
          "lastName": "Lumis"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Result": "Ben F Parker - UNCLE",
      "relation": "UNCLE",
      "relatedParty": {
        "type": "PERSON",
        "fullName": "Ben F Parker",
        "person": {
          "middlename": "F",
          "firstName": "Ben",
          "lastName": "Parker"
        }
      },
      "originatingParty": {
        "type": "PERSON",
        "id": "",
        "fullName": "Peter Parker",
        "person": {
          "middlename": "",
          "firstName": "Parker",
          "lastName": "Peter"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

I would suggest wrapping everything in an Integration Procedure where you do the relation != NULL check externally from the DR Transform, thus the input that the DR Transform gets is clean.
Good luck!

Thank you! I took your advice and wrapped the data raptor in an integration procedure and used one more data raptor to transform the clean input and now getting the correct concatenated Result: "Fullname - Relation", added to the list. Many thanks!

Glad to hear it worked @sflearner. If you do not mind, can you mark my response as the answer. I would really appreciate it.
